# Try to click a togglebutton and make the other togglebutton unchecked. Android Studio-Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, togglebutton, checked

So, hello guys,in android-studio, I've got a horizontal-linear-layout and also got two buttons in it side by side which are togglebuttons, lets call them X and Y, what I'm trying to do is, once I click X, X becomes checked then when I try to click Y, Y becomes checked but X becomes unchecked back, so how would I do it? I try to do this but eventually not worked.

```
    if (beginnerButton.isChecked) {
        balleButton.isChecked = false
    }
    else if (balleButton.isChecked) {
        beginnerButton. = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define OnClick in XML like below

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/beginnerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clickBeginnerButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/balleButton"
        android:onClick="clickBalleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

and in kotlin:

```
  public fun clickBeginnerButton(view: View) {
    balleButton.isChecked = false
  }

  public fun clickBalleButton(view: View) {
    beginnerButton.isChecked = false
  }
```

Its will working as your expected

Hope this helps